# doctrine2 Queries order after a flush

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem in my project using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 because i cant manipulate the order of the queries after a flush...

I have 2 entities with a OneToOne bidirectional relationship : User and Team 
this an example to illustrate the situation i struggle with:

> RedTeam have a  team manager (user) : Mark
>
> GreenTeam have a  team manager (user): Jack

if i change the team manager of Redteam to Jack then i should have

> RedTeam have a  team manager : Jack
>
> GreenTeam have a   team manager : null

here is my entities class with the setters i made

**User :**

```
    class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vci\MainBundle\Entity\Team" , mappedBy="teamManager")
     */
    protected $managedTeam;

    public function setManagedTeam(Team $managedTeam = null) {
        if ($managedTeam != null && $this->managedTeam !=null ) {
            $this->managedTeam->setTeamManager(null);
        }
        $this->managedTeam = $managedTeam ;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Team**

```
    class Team {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vci\MainBundle\Entity\User" , inversedBy="managedTeam")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $teamManager;

     public function setTeamManager(User $teamManager = null) {

        if ($teamManager != null && $this->teamManager!=null) {
            $this->teamManager->setTeamManaged(null);
        }

        $this->teamManager = $teamManager;
        if ($this->teamManager != null) {
            $this->teamManager->setTeamManaged($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**and this is a part of my controller**

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bind($request); // the setter is called here

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $teamManager = $this->get('vci_main.teammanager');


            $teamgreen = $teamManager->findById(2); 
            $teamred = $teamManager->findById(1);
            //the 2 teams are perfectly changed


            //save in database
            $this->em->flush(); // here is a flush and where the exception occure
```

normally the greedteam need to be updated first to avoid the duplicate entry exception but Nooo doctrine2 start always with the RedTeam directly ..

**here is the exception :**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE Team SET teamManager_id = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [13, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13' for key 'UNIQ_64D209219EF091'
```

Comment: What is `$team` in `$teamManager->save($team);`?

Comment: Maybe try oneToMany relations. You can avoid this error I think.

Comment: oh $team is the team that has been updated from a view form in our example : "RedTeam" :)

Comment: thanks i tried the OneToMany relation and it work even if its not realy the logic of the relationship XD

Answer (score 0):

On a one to one relation, you have to unset the team manager of other team first.

I.E. to do :

```
UPDATE team SET manager=:user_id WHERE id=:team_id
```

You need first to perform this :

```
UPDATE team SET manager = null WHERE id=:user_id
```

Why don't have a trigger before update on team ? Trigger are not very good practice, but it will simplify your problem.